# Increase size of partition (ext4) or automount it

Tags: disk, fdisk

I wish to increase size of my `/` partition (current size 21 GB), is that possible somehow? I have more free space available, but don’t know how to add it into the existing partition. I have created a new partition (named Extra, size 12 GB) with that free space and would like to either merge it with `/` or if that’s not possible is there any way to change the mount point. Because the new partition I have created with the free space currently get mounted at `/media/Extra`  and I have to mount it every time I start computer.

Here is the output of sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb8000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63      401624      200781   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          403456    31860735    15728640    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *    31860736   414078967   191109116    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       414081022   625141759   105530369    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       414081024   558030847    71974912    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       583198720   625141759    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       558033903   583191629    12578863+  83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

[image: This is the image from the Disk Utility]
[image: GParted screenshot, 2 ext4 partitions from bottom]

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: It would be useful to include a screen shot from `gparted` or the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and specify which partitions correspond to `/home` and the new partition.

Comment: Sure I will just add the pictures

Comment: +1. You should now be able to add pictures.

Comment: The 21 GB ext4 is /home and 12 GB ext4 is the extra partition I want to add. 
If you cant see the pic clearly here is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mzt82ssp5f1oow/Gparted.png

Answer (score 0):

Delete /dev/sda7 (Extra). This should concatenate unallocated space around it and produce a single unallocated block. After that you should be able to increase /dev/sda6 up to plus that space with Resize operation as described here [How to merge partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66000/how-to-merge-two-partitions)

Comment: Add a few details... this has to be done from a live CD since the `/` partition is currently locked. It will take a long time to resize to the left of the partition. A full backup of data is recommended (also anything on `/dev/sda7` will be lost if not backed up). Grub _may_ need to be reinstalled...

Comment: @shashankgaur, so what are the results? Did it work?