# How do I join my partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I had Ubuntu (150 gb) and zorin os (150 gb). In a hard drive of 320 gb, then using the Disks utilty of Zorin OS 9 which I'm running, tried to delete the Ubuntu one, because I will stay only with Zorin.

Then I noticed that is not so simple. And now that "free space 152 gb" shows as unallocated. My attempts for doing something about that from Zorin failed, I guess because can't do much with the HDD as I'm using an OS running on it right? So even `gparted` couldn't help.

How do I make a gparted USB bootable? Is that the way to go to boot and resize partition to use that unallocated space?

Can someone point me in the right direction, in a step by step guide?

I'm 100% stuck. Made the USB bootable with unetbootin, downloaded the gparted iso, but when I reboot and enter the BIOS, when pick the usb I get "The system found unauthorized changes on firmware, operating system or uefi drivers", and that's all, no joy,  no gparted resizing my partions or merging the unallocated space...

Tried booting with linux mint from bootable usb, and running gparted, but in that case I can't to anything with unallocated space either. I can only resize

[image: my disk partitions]

The dev/sda1 can be shrinked only... I'd like to have a 294 gb hd instead... the unallocated simply doesn't show any options or commands (all grayed out)

If I enter any number on dev/sda1 in "free space preceding" (or following), that is substracted from "new size"....

After doing a `mount´ in terminal I see this:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=fernando)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/fernando/MULTIBOOT type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I guess what I need is to delete the sda2 partition, how do I do that?

Comment: you can run gparted from the ubuntu install disk just choose "try ubuntu without installing"

Comment: Just make Ubuntu USB Live and boot into it, use Gparted to configure your hard drive. Make sure that swap partitions that you may have created while installing both OS are logical ones, there is a limit of 4 primary partitions in every drive. So, this thing can cause issues while editing partition tables. Please give complete partition information. Image can be uploaded to free sites like imageshack.us and link can be posted here. Just FYI.

Comment: upload your shots on http://imgur.com/ and post the links in body of question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/568140/edit). (*I think you will need to remove `http://` in front of links to post them.*)

Comment: Make a visit to this link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/66000/how-to-merge-partitions. Check out first highest voted answer if you want to follow GUI-based steps and check out second highest voted answer if want to follow terminal based steps.

Comment: Fernando, off course you cannot delete this partition, it would remove the "Zorin" you've installed.  You need to delete sda2 which is an extended partition containing nothing any more before you can extend your "Zorin". **Furthermore** as you're not running Ubuntu any more, this question now officially became **blatantly off-topic** and will be flagged as such.

Answer (score 2):

UNetbootin has been dropped from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. When I tested the built-in Startup Disk Creator application as a UNetbootin replacement app with a GParted .iso image it worked in Ubuntu 18.04.

1. [Download](https://gparted.org/download.php) the GParted Live iso file.
2. Run the built-in Startup Disk Creator application, and follow the instructions in the GUI to install GParted Live on your USB flash drive.
3. Back up any important files before you resize the partition. Don't skip this step whatever you do.
4. Resize the partition by following the instructions from: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).

---

I made my GParted live USB from Ubuntu by following the instructions from the [GParted Live on USB](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) website at gparted.org. I used the method described under the heading: **GNU/Linux Method C: UNetbootin**.

1. Install UNetbootin from the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. [Download](https://gparted.org/download.php) the GParted Live iso file.
3. Run the UNetbootin application, and follow the instructions in the GUI to install GParted Live on your USB flash drive.
4. Back up any important files before you resize the partition. Don't skip this step whatever you do.
5. Resize the partition by following the instructions from: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I cannot get that which software is installed in your laptop.

- Download GParted ISO image
- Then download Unetbootin or Tuxboot to make bootable pendrive.
- After installing GParted on USB just reboot and go into BIOS set up (Usually we go into BIOS set up by pressing F2 ,F8, F10 when company logo appear (Buttons Depend on your lappie company)
- After going into BIOS set up go into Boot menu and change the priority of booting options. Set the USB in which you installed Gparted as first priority.Then Save And Exit (Press F10).
- Now you will boot into GParted. Now do what you want to do with your hdd.
- After merging your partition just shut down your computer and take out your pendrive.
- Now enjoy and drink one pine of beer.*Kindly Make Backup of your data and do not move the partion (MEMORY BLOCK) of OS you want to keep becoz then u may loose your data also our corrupt your OS*
- Please notify me in case u face any problem