# Ubuntu to win7 how to

Tags: live-usb, gparted

I have now tuxboot 0.7 and need to do Gparted live usb with it. Can you tell me what gparted file I need to download? 
I tried this once but failed. Tuxboot has usb drive option and after that Drive:and box but it is empty. Should my usb show on that when connected? I can't choose my usb from anywhere. That tuxboot looks different than instructions I found and i tried to update it  but nothing chanced. Can you first advice hot to succeed to make gparted usb.
[tuxboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3f1p.jpg)

When I hit OK I think gparted went to HD I guess and when I tried to go gparted live it was running from HD and not my usb like supposed to.

I think I need to format HD to ntfs but largest part was locked and said something is busy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I join my partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568140/how-do-i-join-my-partitions) the instructions for making a GParted live USB are in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/568140/how-do-i-join-my-partitions/568366#568366

Answer (score 2):

Well Ubuntu 16.04 was not a huge mistake your only mistake is not really understanding what your computer is trying to do.
if your running gparted from a usb that means it is running a LIVE version not installed on your Hard Drive. when this is happening you can not do anything else with that USB. it is Active and can't be formatted you can only run that one LIVE Session.

Not sure why you need gparted anyway and you don't need tuxboot.

I am going on assumptions here but what you need is the gparted ISO file and [Etcher](https://etcher.io/)

Etcher will get you where you need to go BUT if all your doing is installing Ubuntu onto your HD you only need to burn the UBUNTU_16.04.ISO onto your USB with [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) and boot up your computer with that. Ubuntu will take it from there.  it will boot up into a LIVE desktop and all you have to do is double click the install icon that will be on the desktop and the Installer will walk you through it

you might want to try other versions of Ubuntu that will be more like Windows ex. [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/download.php) or [elementry](https://elementary.io/) (My wife loves this one) or find one that fits your [taste](https://distrowatch.com/) there are so many different "Flavors" out there your bound to find one that you love too.

Comment: Thank you. Ubuntu is fine but I don't understand it at all. I cant even save public key to .asc or whatever I need to do to import working key.         I do have ubuntu usb. How do I format to ntfs with that? I can find so many diffent way to do it but no simple instructions.   I can forget tuxboot and geparted if "live" ubuntu can make installing win possible.

Comment: OK "I can't even save public key to asc" not sure what public key your talking about I'm not sure what it is your trying to do. Your post is scattered with no clear talking points.  
Your talking about NTFS Why?

Comment: You Trying to save a Public Key, Why? what is it for/from or used for?
What is your OS right Now?
What are you trying to do?
I have No clear Idea about what your asking?
No one knows the context of your random post. Act like no one has any idea about what your talking about and try again.