# Merging two partitions (Gparted) - Error: Cannot delete partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, merge

Apparently, during the installation of Ubuntu 14.04, it did not delete an existing partition. Now, I want to merge that one with a new one ([How to merge partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66000/how-to-merge-partitions)). However, deletion of the old partition gives this error:

```
Please unmount any logical partitions having a number higher than 6
```

Which I can't do because dev/sda6 is being used while running Ubuntu.

Is there any way to do this from the running Ubuntu? I already read about the option of using a gparted live disk.

The partitions to be merged are dev/sda6 and dev/sda7 (see the below screenshot).

[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90wxJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this from a running system.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
Open GParted and merge the partitions.

Comment: Will this leave the existing data on the NEW partition (the data on the OLD partition has been backed up else-where)?

Comment: @ArminMeisterhirn : The easiest way is to copy the data to another disk ... then delete sda5 and sda6 ... then grow sda7 using the unallocated space, leaving enough free space for swap (size matching RAM) ... then create a new partition and format it with linux-swap. Afterwards copy back the data to sda7. :)