# When I have 2 Ubuntu versions, Can I uninstall one of them?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

If I have two Ubuntu versions installed in my PC, let's say: Ubuntu Studio 15.10 and Lubuntu 15.10, Can I remove one of them (whichever) without to having to format any partition?

Is there some bash command to perform this?

How?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a program to install / uninstall, it is an OS. I suggest you keep both as ubuntu studio is optimized for multimedia and lubuntu is not, so there are differences between the two. Personally I dual boot between Fedora 23 for desktop stuff and KXStudio when in need to record.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That sounds like an answer not a comment

Comment: @ThomasW. -yes and no, it really does not discuss uninstall and potential multiple swap partitions, multiple boot, and cleaning up grub.=, so an opinion/comment really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to actually remove an operating system is by modifying partitions. As @bodhi.zazen said, Ubuntu is not a program that can be uninstalled. That being said, deleting that Ubuntu partition will let you reclaim the space and give it to another partition.

Although, if you aren't running out of space on your hard drive, there's no particular reason to delete the partition. If you do still want to delete it, you can do so via the GUI application GParted as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/66041/205638) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/794/205638).

Comment: Thank you so much (all the people that wrotes soemthing to this issue)!!! But... I had to be extreme: I bought a new HDD and I started all over again, from the scratch. Now, Ubuntu Studio run, so fine, and as the only one OS in this computer. So... the data I wanted to save is on the old (full) HDD and I'll passed to the new HDD, this weekend. Thank you so much, again!!!

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is not a Bash command for this.

Do you know the tool gparted? It's a graphical tool to manage your disk space. Install it in this system, that you want to keep. It's available in Ubuntu-software-center.

With this tool you should be able to delete partition of the other system. Don't forget to start it as root.

Answer (score -2):

There are people way smarter than me here, but is it a dual boot situation? Like, they both are separated by a partition? If so then yes just format the partition of the OS you no longer want. Just save all your stuff first.

Comment: One should also take care of the boot loader (GRUB) to keep it usable...