# How to increase the size of /home?

Tags: gparted

I need to increase the size of my home partition. Since the /home is at the bottom of the list, I really don't have much idea on what l should about it.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Above link is a screenshot of my Gparted application.

As you can see I have 100 GB of unallocated memory.

Is there any way to allocate some of it into my /home partition?

Comment: You need to boot from LIveUSB and use gparted from there.

Comment: @Pilot6 You are absolutely correct, I added that to my answer.

Comment: Well come to AU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

- the quick one: using Gparted, format the 100Gb block as ext4. Let's say most of your stuff is in `/home/username/Videos`. Create a new directory called `/home/username/NewVideos`. Mount the new partition at `/home/username/NewVideos`. Move all of your stuff from `Videos` to `NewVideos`. Remove the (now empty) directory `Videos`, and rename `NewVideos` to `Videos`. Edit `/etc/fstab` so your new partition will automatically be mounted at `/home/username/Videos` at the next reboot.
- the thorough one: You need to boot from a LiveUSB for this. Move your partitions around so the 100Gb unallocated block is next to your /home partition. Then, merge these partitions (see [How to merge partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66000/how-to-merge-partitions)).

In all cases, make sure you have backups of all your data.

Comment: The first option seems cool and I have a feeling that it will work. Thanks

Comment: Is there much concern about the data when using the first option?

Comment: @persistent-poltergeist You won't touch any used partition with Gparted, so no. I would be careful moving the stuff from `Videos` to `NewVideos`, to make sure that the `mount ` command has worked properly. In fact I would do a `rsync` from `Videos` to `NewVideos` before deleting all the stuff in `Videos`.