# Ubuntu not enough storage space

Tags: partitioning, disk, home-directory, storage

I don't have enough storage space in my home directory. How can I increase the storage without reinstalling Ubuntu? Here is what my partitions look like.

[image]

[image]

I don't know what it means. I don't need `/dev/sda4`, how can I add this storage to my home directory?

Comment: here are some examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040986/resizing-home-partition https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304978/how-to-increase-home-partition  https://askubuntu.com/questions/787676/how-to-increase-the-size-of-home  https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: I would suggest installing [bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org), or if you just want basic cleaning, just do `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean`. or you can follow @Rinzwind 's answer

Comment: "/dev/sda4, how can I add this storage to my home directory?" /media are external locations like usb sticks or possibly contain a windows operating system so no,,, you do not want to use those as /home.  Maybe remove some files from /home?

Comment: @Rinzwind How can I do then in order to increase size on /home ?

Comment: There is currently nothing to increase (all the hard disk space is almost full: both / and /home). /media does not apply here. either remove from sda6 and move empty space to sda7 or (re)move files from sda7  to /media/  (depending on what does are: I assume one is a C: and another D:; I would assume you'd want to use d: if possible) .